# How to lock Opportunity Record?

Tags: administration, opportunity, record

How to lock a Opportunity Record if the Stage value is changed to Closed Won or Closed Lost?

I think it can be done using a validation rule but I am not sure and want to have a best approach.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use recordtypes.

Once the Opportunity goes to Closed Won or Closed Lost, use a workflow rule to change the record type to, say, 'Closed'. Then, use a different page layout for the 'Closed' recordtype wherein all the fields are read only on layout 'Closed'

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use validation - 
once the field changes to 'Closed', do not allow it to change - throw a validation error!

Comment: I think this is better than changing the page layout too read only, as this also prevents changes through the API.

Comment: This may cause a significant amount of effort if you need to lock every field, not just the status.

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize an approval process to lock the record after a stage is set.  I allows for audits as well as tracking on 'unlock' requests as well.